# Data is being stripped away from sub properties during the process of sending data from Node/Express server back to React client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express

Some unknown issue is happening while data is being sent from the server to the client that is stripping away data from sub-properties before I can access and perform any action on it.

I cannot replicate this issue anywhere else as querying and returning data works in every other case throughout my application even where code is exactly the same aside from what Model is queried and what sub documents are being populated.

Example of my server code:

```
const myData = await Model.find({ ...queryOptions }).populate({ path: 'subDocument' });

console.log( myData );

return res.status( 200 ).send({
  message: 'success',
  myData
});
```

Server-side `console.log` result:

```
[
  {
    _id: 123,
    title: 'The Title',
    subDocument: {
      _id: 456,
      title: 'The Subdoc',
      items: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    }
  }
]
```

On the client, the following code is run:

```
const response = await axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: '/path-to-api'
});

console.log( response.data );
```

Client-side `console.log` result:

```
{
  message: 'success',
  myData: [
    {
      _id: 123,
      title: 'The Title',
      subDocument: {}
    }
  ]
}
```

For some reason, something is happening while the server response is being sent back that is stripping away the data in  `subDocument`.

There is no extra code being executed between the axios GET request on the client and the `res.send()` on the server.

As written above, the `console.log` on the server is being executed immediately before `res.send()` confirming that the data in `subDocument` IS there and the `console.log` on the client is being executed immediately after the axios GET request has completed confirming that it is NOT there.

Building with the MERN stack.

`MongoDB: v7.0.2` |
`Express: v4.18.2` |
`React: v18.2.0` |
`Node: v21.4.0`

**Update -->> RESOLVED**.

Investigating further, this now looks to have been a problem with (or more likely: my misunderstanding of) React's StrictMode double rendering.

To fix, I had to run `JSON.stringify()` on the object on the server and return it as a string to the client to be parsed with `JSON.parse()`. Which seems strange to do in this context given there are many other controller functions returning the exact same structure of data (even handling *undefined* and **null** without issue like someone made note of). But, doing it this way would at least FORCE the properties and values of that subDocument to exists on the client.

Then, after following `console.log()` to where this data is required to render a component I could see that **InstallHook.js** was not preserving variables.

I was able to get the component to render properly and hold the data with a combination of `useState` and `useEffect` on the child component even though my expected result was that the data should have been preserved on the parent component, which also uses `useState` and `useEffect` and passed back down to the child on re-render.

This seems a bit hack-y as that subDocument property is still being emptied everywhere else for no apparent reason on re-render aside from the child component that has it specifically stored as state. I am not making copies of the object or running something like `delete myData.subDocument` so still not 100% sure what the origin of the problem is. But, my application now works as intended again.

**Thank you to everyone who responded!**

Comment: I doubt it is related, but know that "odd numbered versions" of NodeJS are experimental/development releases.  Unless you are actually developing NodeJS itself, you likely should be working with an Long Term Support (LTS) release -- the even numbered releases.

Comment: `res.send({ ... })` will end up calling `JSON.stringify()` on that object and that will only include enumerable properties of certain data types.  It will not include things that don't have a representation in JSON.  Also, some objects returned by databases have some unusual properties (done for database efficiency reasons) so sometimes, you should build your own plain object from scratch with the properties you want on it and then send that.

Answer (score 0):

`res.send({})` cannot handle all data types, such as `null` and `undefined`.  Consider using `res.json()` instead. [This article](https://medium.com/gist-for-js/use-of-res-json-vs-res-send-vs-res-end-in-express-b50688c0cddf) gives a decent breakdown of the differences.